# Can't call custom repository function in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, orm

We're having problems calling a certain custom entity repository function from our controller in a Symfony2 project. We have successfully done it before with other entities so we're probably missing something and I can't figure out what it could be.

Our repository class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace OurSite\Bundle\OurBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class BlogRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findPreviousPosts($limit = 6)
    {

        $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->where('q.category = :category')            
            ->setMaxResults($limit)                                                           
            ->add('orderBy', 'q.published ASC')
            ->getQuery();
        $res = $q->getResult();
        return $res;
    }
}
```

The entity:

```
<?php

namespace OurSite\Bundle\OurBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* OurSite\Bundle\OurBundle\Entity\Blog
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OurSite\Bundle\OurBundle\Entity\BlogRepository")
*/
class Blog {
    // Non-relevant stuff here
}
```

When we call the method like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$previousPosts = $em->getRepository('OurSiteOurBundle:Blog')->findPreviousPosts();
```

We get this:

```
Undefined method 'findPreviousPosts'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
```

If we do `echo get_class($em->getRepository('OurSiteOurBundle:Blog'));` it outputs `BlogRepository`, as expected.

What could be causing the problem? We have a superfluous `bundle` directory in the project but I'm guessing that can't be causing it?

Comment: What if you add `By` after `find` in the method name and call?

Answer (score 6):

From the source you provided, this may not be your issue, but it may save others some search time.

I was coming across the same "must start with either findBy or..." error, and it turns out in my Entity definition I had accidentally made a call to the @ORM\Entity annotation Twice. The first time I used it properly and set the repositoryClass, but the second time I just used it by itself (as with an Entity that wouldn't have a custom repository) and so that overwrote the previous repositoryClass definition.

```
 /**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Company\TestBundle\Entity\MyEntityRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="testing_my_entity")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class MyEntity
{
etc...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you get this error: `The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!` that means that your custom repository isn't loaded.

Check for typos in the code, clear cache, make sure "OurSiteOurBundle" is the actual shortcut name.

Comment: We've checked and double checked for typos and cleared the cache a few times. We also verified the shortcut name matches - if we add typos to the class name like `'OurSiteOurBundle:Blogxxx'` we get a "class not found" error instead.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja can you add a `echo 'test';exit;` as a first line to `findPreviousPosts` method and see if it's printed? Also try renaming the method to something like `getPreviousPosts`

Comment: Nothing was `echo`ed. Changing the method name to `getPreviousPosts` didn't help either, the error message just changed to `Undefined method 'getPreviousPosts'.`

Comment: So there you have it, your custom repository class isn't loaded. Since this is a feature that's well tested and used all around for all versions, I recommend re-checking again for typos or wrong configuration.

Comment: But please note that `get_class()` for the repository returns `BlogRepository`. I believe it should be `EntityRepository` if the custom repository fails to load.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I've seen many posts about that but nothing solved it.

Finally I found out that was because I was previously using generated yml files, so Doctrine didn't read annotations for mapping !

So just be sure you don't have any yml/xml Doctrine files.

And then :

```
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you used this entity before? I see strange entity shortcut for Blog

> OurSiteOurBundle:Blog

but your Blog have OurSite\ **Bundle**\OurBundle\Entity namespace. I think it should be

> OurSiteBundleOurBundle:Blog

and entity manager points you to wrong repository class

Comment: The entity has been used before, but with no custom repository class methods. Changing the entity shortcut gives the error message `Unknown Entity namespace alias 'OurSiteBundleOurBundle'.`

Answer (score 0):

If use xml for mapping(pass tested):
Update xml or yml mapping file, add repository-class attribute:

```
<entity name="Ccd\Bundle\FrontendBundle\Entity\UvUpdatePageContent" table="uv_update_page_content" **repository-class="Ccd\Bundle\FrontendBundle\Entity\UvUpdatePageContentRepository"**>
```

http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/mapping-classes-to-orm-and-odm.html
Then update doctrine cache:

```
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

use yml(not tested):

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Post:
  type: entity
  table: posts
  RepositoryClass: Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\PostRepository
```